# native typeface cannot be made (type of font cannot be change)

Tags: android, android-typeface

i already create bitmap from the text. but i want to change type of font that used in the bitmap. but it keep native typeface cannot be made. so the type of font cannot be change.

here is my code

```
public void textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    try 
    {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/PROGGY.TTF");
        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("your tag", "typeface error: ", e);
    }

    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.20f); // round 0.5f
    float baseline = (int) (-paint.ascent() + 0.5f); // ascent() is negative
    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.50f); //0.5f
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
    printBitmap(image);

}
```

i store the proggy.ttf in here
[image]

Comment: `"fonts/PROGGY.ttf"` change the `extension` to `.ttf` and try

Comment: also cannot. native typeface cannot be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after exploring, try and error, brainstorming and try everthing. then i found these..

when im using this code. i cannot change my typeface. it keep native typeface cannot be made.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
```

so i solve my problem using this code

```
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
            | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
    textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);

    try
    {
        Typeface tf =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/proggy.ttf");
        textPaint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("your tag", "typeface error: ", e);
    }
```

Then the, "fonts/**proggy.ttf**" need to be the lowercase. When i try it into uppercase it keep native typeface cannot be made. so using the lowercase, then the type of font can be change as i wish. problem solved

thanks for the feedback M D :)